# Querying database using rawQuery in android

Tags: android, mysql, sql

I am writing a simple query that can fetch particular fields record from a table in android.

Here is my table design:

**userid, name, totalmarks, (ALL STRINGS)**

here is my query:

```
public String getTotalMarks(String UserID)
{
    String mark = "0";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 

    String queryMarks = "SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_MARK_DETAILS +" WHERE " +KEY_USERID + " =" + UserID  ;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryMarks, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        do 
        {
            mark = cursor.getString(0);
        } 
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.e("Cursor", "Value" +mark);

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return mark;
}
```

I am getting the perfect results. I wanna know is there a better way to query the database than above?

Comment: If you only need one column, then you could just select that column instead of `select *`. If you only expect one row to ever be returned, then the `do-while` loop is unnecessary; however, if it's possible that the query could return more than one row, then your current code only returns the value in the last row and I would ask whether this is intentional behavior or not.

Comment: @Karakuri - I just need one column result and I will get only one row. Can you give an example on how to get the same results without the loop?

Comment: `if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { mark = cursor.getString(0); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public String getTotalMarks(String UserID) {
        String mark = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
        String queryMarks = "SELECT " + KEY_TOTALMARKS + " FROM " +  TABLE_MARK_DETAILS + " WHERE " +KEY_USERID + " =" + UserID;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryMarks, null);

        if(null != cursor){
            if(cursor.moveToFirst() && 0 < cursor.getCount()){
                mark = cursor.getString(0);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        Log.e("Cursor", "Value" + mark);
        db.close();

        return TextUtils.isEmpty(mark) ? "0" : mark;
    }
```